# Linebreaking an URL without any hyphens - only letters

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref, hyphenation, urls, shortcut

Does anyone know how I can make a linebreak in my LaTeX output so that the link doesn't go "out of bounds"... There aren't any hyphens so I can't make any of the xurl, url, hyperref work. They also ruin all my links?

I need the following link to break anywhere. Does any of you LaTeX pros know how to solve such problem? :D

https://www.bhp.com/-/media/documents/investors/annual-reports/2020/200908_bhpscope12and3emissionscalculationmethodology2020.pdf

### @Misc{bhp2020,
author = {BHP},
title = {Scope 1, 2 and 3 Emissions. Calculation Methodology 2020},
note = {Accessed 2023-03-12},
year = {2020},
url = {https://www.bhp.com/-/media/documents/investors/annual-reports/2020/200908_bhpscope12and3emissionscalculationmethodology2020.pdf},
}

[image]

Comment: Apparently just loading the xurl package in fixed everything

Comment: Why do you claim that "There aren't any hyphens so I can't make ... xurl ... work"? The whole point of the `xurl` package is to allow line breaks *anywhere* in a long URL string.